# Azure Scheduler Job Collection integration with Resource Manager Deployment Model Storage Queue

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues, azure-scheduler

I am attempting to create a new `Azure Scheduler Job` that has a `Storage queue` action, but the only Storage Accounts that I am able to select from my Azure Subscription are "Classic" Storage Accounts, I can not select a "Resource Manager" Storage Account.

Are `Azure Scheduler Job`s not compatible with "Resource Management" Storage Accounts?

Answer (score 3):

Azure Scheduler supports any storage account (either classic or resource manager based) but the portal currently only supports selecting a classic storage account today.  So in the meantime you can use the REST API to add a storage queue action that references a resource manager storage account.

Comment: The REST APIs use a timestamp header called x-ms-date which is required and seems to expire after only about 15 minutes. How would you propose to use the REST API via a static scheduler job created in the portal where this value can't be continuously updated?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, the Preview Portal (portal.azure.com) still doesn't have all intended functionality. Some things are work in progress, like "Resource Management Storage Accounts" in the Storage queue Scheduler job.